# How do I transpose all columns to rows in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to transpose the columns to rows and load it to the data base. My input is the Json file.

```
{"09087":{"values": ["76573433","2222322323","768346865"],"values1": ["7686548898","33256768","09864324567"],"values2": ["234523723","64238793333333","75478393333"],"values3": ["87765","46389333","9234689677"]},"090881": {"values": ["76573443433","22276762322323","7683878746865"],"values1": ["768637676548898","3398776256768","0986456834324567"],"values2": ["23877644523723","64238867658793333333","754788776393333"],"values3": ["87765","46389333","9234689677"]}}
```

Pyspark:

`df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").format("json").load("testfile.json")`

```
Schema:

root
 |-- 09087: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- values1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- values2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- values3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- 090881: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- values1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- values2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- values3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Data:

```
df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               09087|              090881|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|{[76573433, 22223...|{[76573443433, 22...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name        values            values1           values2              values3
09087       76573433          7686548898        234523723            87765
09087       2222322323        33256768          64238793333333       9234689677
09087       768346865         09864324567       75478393333          46389333
090881      76573443433       768637676548898   23877644523723       87765
090881      22276762322323    3398776256768     64238867658793333333 46389333
090881      7683878746865     0986456834324567  754788776393333      9234689677
```

Actually I just gave 2 columns as input but I have lot of them. I have been trying this- could someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which output do you need? 2 columns or 5 columns?

Answer (score 1):

Pyspark translation of my scala solution:

```
from pyspark.sql import 
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([("""{"09087":{"values": ["76573433","2222322323","768346865"],"values1": ["7686548898","33256768","09864324567"],"values2": ["234523723","64238793333333","75478393333"],"values3": ["87765","46389333","9234689677"]},"090881": {"values": ["76573443433","22276762322323","7683878746865"],"values1": ["768637676548898","3398776256768","0986456834324567"],"values2": ["23877644523723","64238867658793333333","754788776393333"],"values3": ["87765","46389333","9234689677"]}}""" )])
df = spark.read.json(rdd)

df.select(\
 explode (\#explode array into rows
  array(\
   *[ struct(\# make a stuct from column name and values 
    lit( col_name ).alias("Name"),\
    col(col_name+".*")\
  ) for col_name in df.columns ])))\
.select(\
  col("col.Name").alias("Name"),\
  explode(\
   arrays_zip(\# make an array of structs from multiple arrays.  The name of the struct.column will be it's index in the orginal array.
    col("col.values"),\
    col("col.values1"),\
    col("col.values2"),\
    col("col.values3")\
   )\
  ).alias("columns")\
).select( col("Name"),col("columns.*")).show()#use '.*' syntax to change struct.column into table.column
+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
|  Name|             0|               1|                   2|         3|
+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
| 09087|      76573433|      7686548898|           234523723|     87765|
| 09087|    2222322323|        33256768|      64238793333333|  46389333|
| 09087|     768346865|     09864324567|         75478393333|9234689677|
|090881|   76573443433| 768637676548898|      23877644523723|     87765|
|090881|22276762322323|   3398776256768|64238867658793333333|  46389333|
|090881| 7683878746865|0986456834324567|     754788776393333|9234689677|
+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//make dummy data

val df = spark.sqlContext.read.json(res4)
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("""{"09087":{"values": ["76573433","2222322323","768346865"],"values1": ["7686548898","33256768","09864324567"],"values2": ["234523723","64238793333333","75478393333"],"values3": ["87765","46389333","9234689677"]},"090881": {"values": ["76573443433","22276762322323","7683878746865"],"values1": ["768637676548898","3398776256768","0986456834324567"],"values2": ["23877644523723","64238867658793333333","754788776393333"],"values3": ["87765","46389333","9234689677"]}}""" )))
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.json(rdd)

df.select( 
 explode ( // explode an array into rows
  array( // make an array
   (for( col_name <- df.columns ) 
   yield 
    struct(  //create struct with names that can be use as columns
     lit(s"$col_name").as("Name") , 
     col(s"$col_name.*")
    )
   ).toSeq :_*  // make sequence into VarArgs
  ).as("rows") 
 ) 
).select( 
  col("col.Name"), 
  expr("explode(
          arrays_zip( 
           col.values , 
           col.values1, 
           col.values2, 
           col.values3)) "  //use array_zip to suck together multiple identical length arrays into 1 array(of structs) with struct containing the names column of the index.
  ).as("columns") 
).select( 
  col("Name"), 
  col("columns.*") // rename as required.
).show()
+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
|  Name|             0|               1|                   2|         3|
+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
| 09087|      76573433|      7686548898|           234523723|     87765|
| 09087|    2222322323|        33256768|      64238793333333|  46389333|
| 09087|     768346865|     09864324567|         75478393333|9234689677|
|090881|   76573443433| 768637676548898|      23877644523723|     87765|
|090881|22276762322323|   3398776256768|64238867658793333333|  46389333|
|090881| 7683878746865|0986456834324567|     754788776393333|9234689677|
+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
```

for more info on [arrays_zip see here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_zip).

Comment: If you found my comment helpful please upvote. If you are comfortable marking it as the answer I'd appreciate you marking it so when you have time.